# AngularJS routing test Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-runner, router

I'm trying to set jasmine test on router like this

```
it('should map routes to controllers and templates', function() {

    inject(function($route) {
        module('igt');

        expect($route.routes['/'].controller).toBe('mainPageCtrl');
        expect($route.routes['/'].templateUrl).toEqual('html/pages/main.html');

        // otherwise redirect to
        expect($route.routes[null].redirectTo).toEqual('/')
    });

});
```

and my router file is (only beggining because it's long):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('igt')
        .config(configure);

    configure.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider'];

    function configure($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'html/pages/main.html',
                controller: 'mainPageCtrl'
            })
```

And I did inject those files in karma.conf.js file:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    '../../node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    '../../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    '../app.js',
    '../router.js',
    'unit/*.js'
],
```

And now when I start test with *karma start* it's giving me error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider <- $route

My entire JS code is encapsulated in IIFE so I don't have even one global variable (I don't know if it matter).

Why I have this error what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change it as

```
describe('Testing Routes', function () {
beforeEach(module('myApp'));
it('should map routes to controllers and templates', function($route) {
  expect($route.routes['/'].controller).toBe('mainPageCtrl');
```

Comment: Now I have `PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) Testing Routes should map routes to controllers and templates FAILED
        TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$route.routes['/']') in unit/testAngularUnitSpec.js (line 4)`

Comment: What's going on?